# How to build a typical REST type system with Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am really confused on how to build a typical REST type web app with Node.js (even though I am using Sockets).

In a typical WAMP stack you have a public javascript file and server-side PHP files. The user might be able to execute a JS function like

function updateDetails(){

```
 $.post('details.php', formData, function(data){
      console.log(data);
   },'json');
}
```

And the server-side PHP file is something like

```
var stmt = "UPDATE table SET user = :user";
var params = (':user', $user);
stmt->execute();
```

Now I do know about node-mysql, but I don't see how it is implemented in the same way. How can I maintain a list of statements on the server side and allow the user to simply execute these statements on the client side.

I have node_modules/mysql installed.

In my server (app.js)

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
```

But unless I add all my statements there, I don't seem to be able to access them from a public JS file.

Comment: The relationship between client code and server code is the same, but your server code happens to also be JavaScript code. Not the *same* JavaScript code, however. Instead of writing your server code in PHP, in other words, you write it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are libraries out there that wrap database tables as resources and expose them as REST services (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).

For example, [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) uses [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs) for this purpose.  You should look into other similar frameworks if you do not want to write the routes from scratch.

If you're *just* using express (4.x), then you can declare routes like the following:

```
// In users.js
var express = require('express');
var users = new express.Router();
users.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    // access mysql, grab all users, then...
    res.json(results);
})
users.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    var userid = req.params.id;
    // access mysql, grab user by id, then...
    res.json(result);
})
users.put('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var newUser = req.body;
    // you can also use POST instead of PUT, and alter where the information for the new user should come from.
    // insert a new row with the data found in newUser then...
    res.json(createdUser);
});
users.delete('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    var userid = req.params.id;
    // delete the user by id then...
    res.json(deletedUser);
});
```

If you're really adventurous, or is a stickler for having http methods do **exactly** what they're supposed to, you can include a PATCH route for updating a user.

You have the option of either including mysql directly in the route, or declaring another module, then referencing that in the route.  I'll finish one of the methods completely.

```
// more complete version of /users/:id
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connectionString = 'fill me in';
var pool = mysql.createPool(connectionString);
users.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    var userid = req.params.id;
    var statement = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE id = ?";
    pool.query(statement, [userid], function (err, rows) {
        if (err) { res.status(500).json(err); } // if you want to expose why you can't get the user by id.
        else if (rows.length == 0) { res.status(404); } // could not find user with the given id.
        else { res.json(rows[0]); } // return the found user.
    });
})
```